# R - How to calculate frequence in r

Tags: r

I am new with R and i have data like this

```
Name    Time     Freq
A       35       7
B       0        1
...
```

I need to calculate frequency = Freq/Time if time = 0 then frequency=1

```
Name    Time     Freq   frequency
A       35       7         0.2
B       0        1          1
...
```

I think it very easy but i can't do it now.
Thanks for any help

Comment: Have a look [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data.frame is named `df`:

Get the frequency:

`df$frequency <- df$Freq / df$Time`

Then convert the infinite entries to 1:

`df$frequency[is.infinite(df$frequency)] <- 1`

Comment: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "frequency", value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 400

Comment: How can i fix this

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround would be using `ifelse` statement:

```
df$frequency <- ifelse(df$time == 0, 1, df$freq/df$time)
```

`df`:

```
  time freq frequency
1   35    7       0.2
2    0    1       1.0
```

Comment: "Error in `/.difftime`(data2$Freq, data2$time) : 
  second argument of / cannot be a "difftime" object"

Comment: I use this code but i get this error. What should i do next ?

Comment: I assume you are working with difftime objects. You should convert them to int first.

Comment: How can i do that?. I really don't know